# jqPlot Chart graph line issue

Tags: jquery, html, charts

I have used jqPlot Chart in my web page from `http://www.jqplot.com/deploy/dist/examples/fillBetweenLines.html.`  All graph lines are solid. I want to change the blue solid line to dashed. If I change the solid to dashed, it will affect the other lines also. How can i do? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can specify the options for all series using seriesDefaults. If you want to change just one series you need to specify that explicitly using the series option.

http://www.jqplot.com/docs/files/jqPlotOptions-txt.html

See the series section in the documentation. You can use the same settings that are available in the seriesDefaults section in the series section.